# VS Code - can you display a Python shell

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When using Python IDLE I find the Python shell, with the >>> prompt very useful for testing syntax. Is there a way of getting a Python shell integrated in VS Code?

Maybe the answer is just to open Python IDLE in another window.

Apparently this is a duplicate of another question, but I did several searches on the words Python shell and didn't find anything that seemed relevant. Sorry.

Many thanks to Jaxi for the answer that you need to type Python in the Terminal Window.

Comment: Using the `Terminal` tab and typing `python`?

Comment: Also: [Integrated Terminal documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) for configuring your own terminal.

Comment: For interactive shell I use python -i name_of_program.py

Answer (score 0):

stated here you can use ctrl+backtick to open a terminal window, then from there just type `python` and it will give you the python shell:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: Oops, got closed as i was answering